# user of preg_match and preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

```
<?php
     $flag=true;
   if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
   if(isset($_POST['text'])){
     $a=$_POST["text"]; 
  } else {
     $a='';
  }
    if(!empty($_POST['msg'])){
      $b=$_POST['msg'];
      $c=strlen($b);}
    if(isset($_POST['wrd'])){
      $d=($_POST["wrd"]);   
    } else {
      $d='';
      }                                                                                        
    if(preg_match("[\w\s.,a-zA-Z$a,\.]",$b)){
      $flag=false;
      }
    if($flag){
     $i;
    for($i=0;$i<=$c;$i++)
    {
       $newtext = str_replace($a,$d,$b);
       echo $newtext;
       echo "</br>";
       break;
    }
 } else {
       echo"not found ";}
 }
  ?>
```

This is my code I want to match word(paragraph) from a original paragraph but the problem is this.
In one line the word (paragraph) is written like this (paragraph,) and (paragraph.)
That's why `preg_match` is not able to find the these two word and same goes to `preg_replace` also.

Comment: Your code formatting and variables naming are awful.

Comment: That's an unreadable mess. If you want help, start by making your code readable so potential helpers don't have to fight back a migraine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
if(preg_match("[\w\s.,a-zA-Z$a,\.]",$b))
```

Regex needs start and end delimiters. It should be:

```
if(preg_match("/[\w\s.,a-zA-Z$a,\.]/", $b))
```

**Also note that** your regex is also incorrect. I can see few mistakes (there myay be more):

1. inside square brackets you don't need to escape dot
2. you seem to have another dot that will match ANY character
3. You have `\w` that means word character hence you don't need separate `a-zA-Z`
4. You have a misplaced a after $ sign